# Marketing cloud page insert row using onclick event

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I have this image

```
<img src="%%=v(@link)=%%" onclick="registerClick()">
```

and the following function

```
function registerClick(){
   alert('click');
   %%[ outputline('OUTPUT') ]%%
}
```

but the ampscript code does not run, what can i use in this situation to after a dom event insert rows at one data extension?

Answer (score 3):

AMPScript and SSJS will only run at the server-side which is before the code is passed to the client/browser. This means that they will never see nor be able to interact with either of these languages. To that affect, you cannot directly call AMPScript nor SSJS in client-side code.

If you need this capability, you can create a Code Resource page that is essentially a 'processing page' that you can hit via an AJAX POST to this page and it will then, on the server side collect the data you pass and then run the AMPScript to insert into a data extension. I would highly recommend encrypting the passed information and to secure the code resource so it does not leave an open door for malicious activities.

You can get some info on building this page in the following places:

**[AMPScript.xyz](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/build-html-forms-without-smart-capture/)**
**[Gortonington.com](https://gortonington.com/sfmc-custom-de-retrieve-rest-api-endpoint/)**
**[markus.codes (security)](https://markus.codes/2020/05/25/securing-cloudpages-with-ssjs-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud)**

Comment: Tnks! I will test this